# wagtail rawhtmlblock error?

Tags: python, wagtail

I'm trying to test out `wagtail` `RawHTMLBlock`, here is my code (models.py):

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from wagtail.wagtailcore import blocks
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel


class HomePage(Page):
    body = StreamField([
        ('raw_html', blocks.RawHTMLBlock()),
    ])

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body')
    ]
```

Now I'm trying to add one HomePage and add some html to body in admin section of my site, but I can't do it, because I'm getting this js error in `chrome's` console:

```
stream.js:87 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initializer' of undefined
    at Object.onInitializeMember (stream.js:87)
    at postInsertMember (sequence.js:95)
    at Object.self.insertMemberAtStart (sequence.js:196)
    at Object.onChooseBlock (stream.js:140)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (stream.js:60)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.1.min.js:3)
```

wagtail version is `1.13.1`, any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StreamField`s need to use `StreamFieldPanel`, not `FieldPanel`.

```
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import StreamFieldPanel

# ...
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('body')
    ]
```